# Why does my iOS App crash on launch when I run it on my iPhone without Xcode 7.1.2?

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

I am developing an iPhone application and it builds successfully without any errors. When my iPhone is connected, it runs successfully. 
When I disconnect the iPhone from my laptop, close the app and try to launch it, it crashes. 
I am using Xcode 7.1.2 and building against iOS 9.2. I have an iPhone 5S. I need some help here... thanks

Comment: Is there any code that you run on app launch? If yes, share it. Are your provisioning profiles and certificates correct?

Comment: You can try to see if any crash code is generated in the iPhone's Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostics & Usage Data. (This could be a result of some race condition changes, like not printing to console)

Comment: I finally found the solution! Had to simply restart my laptop and clean Xcode! thanks a lot!!